# CodeBlocks quits unexpectedly on Mac OS

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, codeblocks

I have installed CodeBlocks on MacBook Air. I have XCode 4.6 and XCode Command Line Tools installed. But the problem is any time I try to open an existing project CodeBlock quits unexpectedly. If I create a new project CodeBlocks crushes the same way when I open any .cpp file of the project. Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. If anyone have the same issue try disabling Code Completion plugin in CodeBlocks (Plugins -> Manage plugins, find 'Code completion' in the list, click 'Disable').

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Yosemite, CB 13.12 still crushes

Comment: Your fix worked for a while on OS X 10.11, but mine is still crashing at an annoying frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeBlocks site says "Code::Blocks for Mac is currently not as stable as are other ports, especially on Mountain Lion. In other words, we could use an extra Mac developer (or two) to work on Mac compatibility issues."
It's likely that it will just crash.